# dxf rotation and georeference

Tags: qgis, vector, georeferencing, vertical-transformation

I have a DXF (layout) which is to be spatially adjusted to a point shapefile that has correct X Y cords.

When I add both as vector layers to Qgis, point shapefile is right on place but dxf shows a single line. I assume it needs rotation.

Vector bender, Vector transformation, Affine Transformation, DXFtoshapeconverter, I tried it all but nothing works.

I need help in understanding the process in such cases, where first I need to rotate the layer to match XY plane of the target layer and then georeference.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do something similar, my solution is to draw a line (in AutoCAD) between two known points (from your point shape, for example) and then move all the draw to fit with that line.